# Загрузка картинки в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Нужно загрузить изображение в папку uploads, по запросу.

```
function image_test(WP_REST_Request $request){
$check1 = current_user_can('upload_files');
$check2 = !function_exists('wp_handle_upload');
if ($check2 && $check2) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';

    $movefile = media_handle_upload($_FILES['test'], 0, array(), ['test_form' => false]);
    // wp_handle_upload($_FILES['test'], ['test_form' => false], '2021/11');
    return $movefile;
}}
```

когда отправляю изображение используя media_handle_upload(); То получаю ошибку от водпреса "Specified file failed upload test.", если же использую очень похожую wp_handle_upload() то изображение загружается, но просто в дерикторию uploads, тоесть дальше работать в вордпресе я с ним не могу.

Comment: [media_handle_upload()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/media_handle_upload) обратите внимание на первый параметр, попробуйте `media_handle_upload('test', 0, array(), ['test_form' => false])`

Comment: спасибо, это сработало